Как вытянуть значение конкретной ячейки из DataFrame по условию и вставить в новый столбец другого DataFrame?
Имеется два датафрейма: df1 с названиями компаний, ИНН и кредитным рейтингом и df2 с ценными бумагами. Общий столбец ИНН. Требуется вытащить из df1 значение кредитного рейтинга в соответствии с ИНН и создать в df2 новый столбец df2['Credit_ratio'] с полученными значениями. Методы loc и isin никакой пользы не принесли. Также стоит как-то учесть, что некоторые компании могут не иметь рейтинга (вообще отсутствуют в df1). В такие ячейки неплохо бы проставить ноли. Владею программированием на уровне дна, сам финансист, поэтому не смейтесь сильно).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный способ.
import pandas as pd


data1 = [['A', '7478399993', '75'], ['B', '4839948823', '56'], ['C', '74819984839', '81']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Company', 'INN', 'Credit_ratio'])



data2 = [['N57', '1000', '13 JAN', '15', '7478399993'], ['N58', '500', '22 JAN', '12', '4845948823'], \
         ['N60', '1000', '10 FEB', '18', '4839948823'], ['N61', '1000', '5 JAN', '10', '4449948823'], \
         ['N62', '900', '29 JAN', '18', '7478399993'], ['N63', '1000', '10 JUN', '14', '4839948823']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Number', 'Value', 'Date', 'Percent', 'INN'])

Благодарю!

Вопрос подозрительно похож на вчерашний вопрос тоже про ИНН. На курсах каких-то эти задачи дают? Используйте merge, как я уже писал в том вопросе.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1584818/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-dataframe-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5/1584828#1584828

@CrazyElf не совсем, здесь нужно получить не датафрейм, а новый столбец. В том вопросе похоже, но не то

@CrazyElf в той задаче требовалось найти перечень ценных бумаг по ИНН (получить фрейм). А здесь на основе ИНН (общий столбец) вытащить значение кредитного рейтинга в новый столбец уже существующего фрейма

Нашел вариант:
import pandas as pd


data1 = [['A', '7478399993', '75'], ['B', '4839948823', '56'], ['C', '74819984839', '81']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Company', 'INN', 'Credit_ratio'])



data2 = [['N57', '1000', '13 JAN', '15', '7478399993'], ['N58', '500', '22 JAN', '12', '4845948823'], \
         ['N60', '1000', '10 FEB', '18', '4839948823'], ['N61', '1000', '5 JAN', '10', '4449948823'], \
         ['N62', '900', '29 JAN', '18', '7478399993'], ['N63', '1000', '10 JUN', '14', '4839948823']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Number', 'Value', 'Date', 'Percent', 'INN'])

df2 = df2.merge(df1, how='outer')
df2.drop(['Company'], axis= 1 , inplace= True )


fillna(0) забыли для "В такие ячейки неплохо бы проставить ноли"

да, еще заменил outer на left, так точнее по-моему будет

Ну вот, а говорите не то )
